# How to run code when a class is subclassed?

Tags: python, inheritance

Is there a way to trigger code when my class is subclassed?

```
class SuperClass:
    def triggered_routine(subclass):
        print("was subclassed by " + subclass.__name__)

magically_register_triggered_routine()

print("foo")

class SubClass0(SuperClass):
    pass

print("bar")

class SubClass1(SuperClass):
    print("test")
```

Should output

```
foo
was subclassed by SubClass0
bar
test
was subclassed by SubClass1
```

Comment: Use a metaclass; metaclasses are called when classes are created, just as classes are called when instances are created.

Comment: Can't add an answer, but today python3.6 have the `__init_subclass__` - check it out!

Comment: @OrDuan: thanks, sounds useful. Might even be reason enough to un-mark this question a duplicate, since there is now a dedicated solution for my problem instead of the "use a metaclass" one.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Classes (by default) are instances of `type`.
Just as an instance of a class `Foo` is created by `foo = Foo(...)`,
an instance of `type` (i.e. a class) is created by `myclass = type(name, bases, clsdict)`.

If you want something special to happen at the moment of class-creation, then you have to modify the thing creating the class -- i.e. `type`. The way to do that is to define a subclass of `type` -- i.e. a metaclass.

*A metaclass is to its class as a class is to its instance.*

In Python2 you would define the metaclass of a class with

```
class SuperClass:
    __metaclass__ = Watcher
```

where `Watcher` is a subclass of `type`.

In Python3 the syntax has been changed to

```
class SuperClass(metaclass=Watcher)
```

Both are equivalent to

```
Superclass = Watcher(name, bases, clsdict)
```

where in this case, `name` equals the string `'Superclass'`, and `bases` is the tuple `(object, )`. The `clsdict` is a dictionary of the class attributes defined in the body of the class definition.

Note the similarity to `myclass = type(name, bases, clsdict)`.

So, just as you would use a class's `__init__` to control events at the moment of a instance's creation, you can control events at the moment of a class's creation with a metaclass's `__init__`:

---

```
class Watcher(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        if len(cls.mro()) > 2:
            print("was subclassed by " + name)
        super(Watcher, cls).__init__(name, bases, clsdict)

class SuperClass:
    __metaclass__ = Watcher


print("foo")

class SubClass0(SuperClass):
  pass

print("bar")

class SubClass1(SuperClass):
  print("test")
```

prints

```
foo
was subclassed by SubClass0
bar
test
was subclassed by SubClass1
```

Comment: Thanks. However, your code only works in python2. In python3, SuperClass would need to be `class SuperClass(metaclass = Watcher): pass`

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the post to address the difference in Python2 and Python3 syntax.

Comment: Two key things that I missed when I tried this on my own: 1 - `Watcher` subclasses `type`, not `object`. 2 - `SuperClass` has no superclass at all, not `object`. I'm just so used to writing down `object` as a superclass for every class I defined that I somehow missed it that this code was using something else. Although there doesn't seem to be any harm in making `SuperClass` inherit from `object`... it's definitely necessary for `Watcher` to inherit from `type`, not `object`.

Comment: To update the solution in python3 and add usage of abstract classes (as i see that proper when we require such registry):
```
import abc

class Watcher(abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, clsdict):
        if len(cls.mro()) > 2:
            print("was subclassed by " + name)
        super().__init__( name, bases, clsdict)

class SuperClass( metaclass=Watcher):
   @abc.abstractmethod
   def method():
       pass

class SubClass0(SuperClass):
  def method():
      print("S0 ok")

class SubClass1(SuperClass):
    pass
  
s1 = SubClass0()
s1 = SubClass1()
```

Answer (score 13):

Edit: My old post actually didn't work.  Subclassing from `classmethod` doesn't work as expected.

First, we would like to have some way to tell the metaclass that this particular method is supposed to have the special called on subclass behavior, we'll just set an attribute on the function we'd like to call.  As a convenience, we'll even turn the function into a `classmethod` so that the real baseclass it was found in can be discovered, too.  We'll return the classmethod so that it can be used as a decorator, which is most convenient.

```
import types
import inspect

def subclass_hook(func):
    func.is_subclass_hook = True
    return classmethod(func)
```

We're also going to want a convenient way to see that the `subclass_hook` decorator was used.  We know that `classmethod` has been used, so we'll check for that, and only then look for the `is_subclass_hook` attribute.

```
def test_subclass_hook(thing):
    x = (isinstance(thing, types.MethodType) and
         getattr(thing.im_func, 'is_subclass_hook', False))
    return x
```

Finally, we need a metaclass that acts on the information:  For most cases, the most interesting thing to do here is just check each of the supplied bases for hooks.  In that way, super works in the least surprising way.

```
class MyMetaclass(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        super(MyMetaclass, cls).__init__(name, bases, attrs)

        for base in bases:
            if base is object:
                continue
            for name, hook in inspect.getmembers(base, test_subclass_hook):
                hook(cls)
```

and that should do it.

```
>>> class SuperClass:
...     __metaclass__ = MyMetaclass
...     @subclass_hook
...     def triggered_routine(cls, subclass):
...         print(cls.__name__ + " was subclassed by " + subclass.__name__)

>>> class SubClass0(SuperClass):
...     pass
SuperClass was subclassed by SubClass0

>>> class SubClass1(SuperClass):
...     print("test")
test
SuperClass was subclassed by SubClass1
```