# Python subclass counter

Tags: python, counter, subclass, init

I have this python code. The result is `TopTest: attr1=0, attr2=1` for X which is fine but the result is `SubTest: attr1=2, attr2=3` for Y which I don't quite understand.

Basically, I have a class attribute, which is a counter, and it runs in the `__init__ method`. When I launch Y, the counter is set to 2 and only after are the attributes are assigned. I don't understand why it starts at 2. Shouldn't the subclass copy the superclass and the counter restart at 0?

```
class AttrDisplay: 
  def gatherAttrs(self):        
    attrs = []        
    for key in sorted(self.__dict__):            
        attrs.append('%s=%s' % (key, getattr(self, key)))        
    return ', '.join(attrs)
  def __repr__(self):        
    return '[%s: %s]' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.gatherAttrs())

class TopTest(AttrDisplay): 
    count = 0        
    def __init__(self):            
        self.attr1 = TopTest.count            
        self.attr2 = TopTest.count+1            
        TopTest.count += 2

class SubTest(TopTest):
    pass

X, Y = TopTest(), SubTest()         
print(X)                            
print(Y)
```

Answer (score 2):

You access and use explicitly `TopTest.count`, and your subclass will stick to this explicitness. You might want to consider to use `type(self).count` instead, then each instance will use its own class's variable which can be made a different one in each subclass.

To make your subclass have its own class variable, just add a `count = 0` to its definition:

```
class SubTest(TopTest):
    count = 0
```

Comment: `self.count += 2` would create instance variable, leaving the class variable intact

Comment: Right, my mistake.  I'm gonna fix it.

Comment: _I know i only criticize, but:_ To avoid using the double underscores, you _could_ use `count = [0]`, but _should_ use `type(self)`. 1-element list is just ugly workaround for a problem that already has a solution.

Comment: I like that constructive critique ;-) and removed the reference-stuff again.  Using explicitly a class variable is probably more Pythonic than using the poor-man's-references.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to keep a counter for each instance of each subclass of `TopTest`, but you do not want to repeat yourself by declaring a new `count` class variable for each subclass.  You can achieve this using a Metaclass:

```
class TestMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_class.count = 0
        return new_class

class TopTest(AttrDisplay, metaclass=TestMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = self.count
        self.attr2 = self.count + 1
        self.increment_count(2)
    @classmethod
    def increment_count(cls, val):
        cls.count += val

class SubTest(TopTest):
    pass
```

The `count` attribute of your `x` and `y` objects should now be independent, and subsequent instances of `TopTest` and `SubTest` will increment the `count`:

```
>>> x, y = TopTest(), SubTest()
>>> x.attr2
1
>>> y.attr2
1
>>> y2 = SubTest()
>>> y2.attr2
3
```

However, metaclasses can be confusing and should only be used if they are truly necessary.  In your particular case it would be much simpler just to re-define the `count` class attribute for every subclass of `TopTest`:

```
class SubTest(TopTest):
    count = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close - when you look up a property of an object, you're not necessarily looking up a property belonging to the object itself. Rather, lookups follow Python's [**method resolution order**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848647), which... isn't entirely simple. In this case, however, only three steps are performed:

1. Check if `Y` has a property named `count`.
2. It doesn't, so check if its class `SubTest` has a property named `count`.
3. It doesn't, so check if its parent `TopTest` has a property named `count`. It does, so access that.

Simply put, when you access `Y.count`, **you're actually accessing `TopTest.count`**.

---

There's also the fact that you have a bug in your code - SubTest increments `TopTest`'s count and not its own. The title of your question says "subclass counter", but since you're counting in `__init__()` I assume you're looking for an **instance counter** (to count subclasses I'm fairly certain [you'd need to use metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126552/python-run-code-when-a-class-is-subclassed)). This is a perfect use case for `self.__class__`, a property which contains an object's class! In order to use it:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.attr1 = self.__class__.count
    self.attr2 = self.__class__.count + 1            
    self.__class__.count += 2
```

Using that, `SubTest.count` will be incremented instead of `TopTest.count` when you call `SubTest()`.

Comment: isn't `cls = type(self)` better?

Comment: @then0rTh You're right, I'm just so used to using `super()`, hahah. `super()` would actually get `TopTest` in this case! I've gone ahead and changed it to `__class__`, which works just as well as `type()` (and also supports old-style classes).

Answer (score 0):

When a new instance of `SubTest` is created `TopTest.__init__()` is called - since `SubTest` inherited `TopTest.__init__()` - which increments `TopTest.count` by two.

And since `SubTest` never defines a class level `count` variable, when `SubTest.count` is executed, Python falls back and uses `TopTest.count`.

This behavior can be fixed by redefining `count` local to `SubTest`.

```
class SubTest(TopTest):
    count = 0
```

Comment: `You can fix this by redefining count inside SubTest` - but you are modifying `TopTest.count` in init, `SubTest.count` will be forever 0

Comment: @then0rTh Right. I'm not sure I follow. Is that not the behavior the OP wanted?

Comment: I thought `SubTest.count` should count instances of `SubTest`, but i may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want each class to have it's own class variable implicitly, you can use a metaclass to add in this variable.

```
class MetaCount(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_cls = super(MetaCount, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new_cls.count = 0
        return new_cls

class Parent(metaclass=MetaCount):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr1 = self.count            
        self.attr2 = self.count + 1            
        type(self).count += 2 # self.count += 2 creates an *instance* variable

class Child(Parent):
    pass


p, c = Parent(), Child()         
print(p.count) # 2                           
print(c.count) # 2
```

Comment: This code fails in Python 3. [That is because Python 3 changed the way metaclass were specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013249/metaclass-in-python3-5). You need to do `Parent(metaclass=MetaCount):` instead of `__metaclass__ = MetaCount` inside of `Parent`.

Comment: @Christian updated, thanks, my machine running 2.7 and I'm too lazy to REPL