# Automatically run some code when subclass is declared

Tags: javascript

It should be something like:

```
class C {
    static m() { console.log('hi') }
}

// automatically run C.m
class D extends C { }
```

A [python case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126552/how-to-run-code-when-a-class-is-subclassed) is found. Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't think you can. but why do you want to do this? any use cases?

Comment: I think you can with custom transpiler like custom babel plugin.

Comment: It's not possible*, but what's the point anyway? Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please explain what you want to achieve with this. --- *: Well, there may be one super quirky way, but I think therein lies madness: You could make the `prototype` property a getter or use a proxy that listens on get operations of the `prototype` property. The line `class D extends C {}` _does_ invoke a read operation on the property `C.prototype`. But the next challenge would be to differentiate this situation from other accesses of that property (e.g. during `new C()` or manualy access).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355812/javascript-execute-function-in-es6-class-on-extend

Comment: The duplicated question answer is different.

Comment: @kennarddh The answer is wrong, but the question is the same

Answer (score 4):

Javascript doesn't have a metaclass per se, but you can create a pseudo metaclass by defining a class within a function:

```
function C() {
    class Cls {
      static m() { console.log('hi') }
    }
    Cls.m()
    return Cls
}

class D extends C() {} // prints 'hi'
```

Comment: Looks weird and not clean.

Comment: @kennarddh I agree, but that's as close as you can get to a metaclass as far as I'm aware

Comment: @kennarddh true, but I don't believe a much cleaner method would be possible.

Comment: A cleaner method is you need to create your own babel transpiler to transpile the source code to transpiled code and add `extendedClass.onExtend()` after the class definition.

Comment: @kennarddh I haven't written in Javascript in years, so I'm not familiar with babel.  That seems like it would make for a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In JS, you can't automatically run code when a subclass is declared.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using custom transpiler.

I have made a [babel plugin library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-event-on-class-extend) to solve this problem.

```
class Y extends X {}

// This package will always add this after every class that extends other class
X?.onExtend?.(Y)
```

You can see the babel plugin implementation [here](https://github.com/kennarddh/babel-plugin-event-on-class-extend/blob/9b2bd069df32c816ca0cbd441c9fd4f692be12f3/src/index.ts)

[This package demo](https://github.com/kennarddh/test-babel-plugin-event-on-class-extend)